# What is unittest in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

What is the meaning of lines 3,16,17,18 and 19 which are highlighted with *. Can someone explain what they do? I am new to python and programming

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver

**class Iframe(unittest.TestCase):**

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def test_Iframe(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('http://www.toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/')

    iframe1 = driver.find_element_by_id('IF1')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)

    driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('xyz')

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')

    print(len(list))

**def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()**


**if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only three lines in this code are highlighted with an *, but here's what they mean:

### First line:

```
 class Iframe(unittest.TestCase):
```

This is declaring the **class** for the functions (*test_Iframe* and *tearDown*) that follow. A [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) is used to create "objects" in [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Think of the **class** as the abstraction of data/procedures, while the **object** is the particular instance of the class.

### Next line:

```
def tearDown(self):
self.driver.quit()
```

This section first declares a function with the `def` keyword, and the function quits the driver, which was set as:

```
driver = self.driver
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/')
```

in the `test_Iframe()` function.

### Final line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

This section simply executes the main function of the program. More details on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Let me know if you have any more questions!

Answer (score 2):

As you have choosen to use Python’s **unittest** here is the relevant info:

- `import unittest`: You need to import the required *unittest* module as a mandatory measure.
- `class Iframe(unittest.TestCase):`: The testcase class is inherited from *unittest.TestCase*. Inheriting from *TestCase* class is the way to tell the *unittest* module that this is a testcase.
- `def setUp(self):`: The *setUp* is the part of initialization and this method will get called before every test function which you are going to write in this testcase class.
- `def test_Iframe(self):`: This is the actual *testcase* method. The *testcase* method should always start with the characters *test*.
- `def tearDown(self):`: The *tearDown* method will get called after every test method. This is the method to do all the cleanup actions.
- `if __name__ == '__main__':`: This line sets the `__name__` variable to have a value `"__main__"`. If this file is being imported from another module then `__name__` will be set to the other module's name. You will find a detailed discussion in [What does if **name** == "**main**": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?)
- `unittest.main()`: Invokes the *test functions* from the configured module.

> Note A: For more details see [Using Selenium to write tests](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests) and [Walk through of the example](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#walk-through-of-the-example)

---

> Note B: Refer [A module's **name**](http://ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/module-name.html) for complete details.

---

### Why self

The first argument of every class method, including `init` is always a reference to the current instance of the *class*. By convention, this argument is always named self. In the `init` method, `self` refers to the newly created object while in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called.

---

### Trivia

[The self variable in python explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Hi Debanjan, Why do we use self here?

Comment: @Aayush Check out my answer update and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Debanjan, Thanks for the explanation. Can you please site an example for this.How this works and why it is necessary?
As I am a newbie in programming.I don't have any prior knowledge of any language and OOPs and I am not able to fully understand the content in books.

Comment: Hi Debanjan, This link https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/ was really helpful. Do u have a same type of link for Unittest??

Comment: @Aayush Go through the links in _Note A_ and _Note B_ which covers the basic understandings.

Comment: Hi Debanjan,
I have one doubt in below lines
"class Iframe(unittest.TestCase): : The testcase class is inherited from unittest.TestCase. Inheriting from TestCase class is the way to tell the unittest module that this is a testcase."
In this , can't we just write like this - class Iframe(TestCase)?