# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such session while executing testcases through Python unittest module

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-unittest

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class KenLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_globe(self):

        global driver

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:\Learning\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.maximize_window()

    def test_login(self):



        driver.implicitly_wait(2000)
        driver.get("http://qa.kenzen.com")
        username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")
        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")

        username.send_keys("pardeepk@clovity.com")
        password.send_keys("Kenzen@123")

        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/button")

        button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        print("Login Pass")


    def test_home(self):

        driver.implicitly_wait(2000)

        teamsummary = driver.find_element_by_id("teamsummary")

        teamsummary.click()
        print("Home Pass")

    def test_newteam(self):

        addteam = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li/button")

        addteam.click()

        teamname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")#.send_keys(data)

        admin = driver.find_element_by_id("administrator")
        admin.send_keys("qa@kenzen.com,qa1@kenzen.com")
        addteambutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/button")
        addteambutton.click()

        print("Team Added")

    def tearDown(self):
        driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

I am trying to run more than 1 functions and getting the error :

Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_home (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 37, in
>   test_home
>       driver.implicitly_wait(2000)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 895, in implicitly_wait
>       'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000})   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_home (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 60, in
>   tearDown
>       driver.close()   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 681, in close
>       self.execute(Command.CLOSE)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_login (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 21, in
>   test_login
>       driver.implicitly_wait(2000)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 895, in implicitly_wait
>       'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000})   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_login (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 60, in
>   tearDown
>       driver.close()   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 681, in close
>       self.execute(Command.CLOSE)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_newteam (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 46, in
>   test_newteam
>       addteam = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li/button")
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 387, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 957, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_newteam (kenZen.KenLogin.KenLogin)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Learning\Workplace\kenZen\kenZen\KenLogin.py", line 60, in
>   tearDown
>       driver.close()   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 681, in close
>       self.execute(Command.CLOSE)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Pardeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such
>   session   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 7.928s

FAILED (errors=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

While working with [***Python***](https://www.python.org/)  and [**unittest**](http://pythontesting.net/framework/unittest/unittest-introduction/) you need to take care of the following:

- **`def setUp(self)`**: The *setUp()* is the part of initialization and this method will get called before every test function which you are going to write in this testcase class.
- **`maximize_window()`**: Instead of using `maximize_window()` use **`chrome.options`** class to maximize the browser window.
- **`implicitly_wait()`**: [**Implicit Wait**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) once set, the *implicit wait* is set for the life of the *WebDriver* object instance.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Here is your own code block with the minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  class KenLogin(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          global driver
          options = Options()
          options.add_argument("start-maximized")
          options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
          options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
          cap = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
          cap = options.to_capabilities()
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

      def test_login(self):
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(2000)
          self.driver.get("http://qa.kenzen.com")
          username = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")
          password = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")
          username.send_keys("pardeepk@clovity.com")
          password.send_keys("Kenzen@123")
          button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/button")
          button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
          print("Login Pass")

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Login Pass
  .
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 1 test in 13.731s

  OK
  ```

---

As per your comment update if you want `setup()` function to be called only once, you can use the [**`setUpClass`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) and [**`tearDownClass`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) class methods which gets executed before and after the tests when a class gets executed.

- Here is your own code block with the minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  class KenLogin(unittest.TestCase):

      @classmethod
      def setUpClass(self):
          global driver
          options = Options()
          options.add_argument("start-maximized")
          options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
          options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
          cap = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
          cap = options.to_capabilities()
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

      def test_login(self):
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(2000)
          self.driver.get("http://qa.kenzen.com")
          username = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")
          password = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")
          username.send_keys("pardeepk@clovity.com")
          password.send_keys("Kenzen@123")
          button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/button")
          button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
          print("ENTER Key pressed")

      def test_print_success(self):
          print("Login Pass")

      @classmethod
      def tearDownClass(self):
          self.driver.quit()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ENTER Key pressed
  .Login Pass
  .
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 2 tests in 18.187s

  OK
  ```

---

### References

- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**What is unittest in selenium Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503046/what-is-unittest-in-selenium-python/49516313#49516313)
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**Unittest setUp/tearDown for several tests**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389639/unittest-setup-teardown-for-several-tests)
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**Run setUp only once**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305941/run-setup-only-once)

Comment: And If I dont want setup() function to be called again and again only once ?

Comment: @PardeepKochhar Checkout my answer update and let me know the status