# Selenium Edge Python errors auto close Edge browser after test execution

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to test selenium for a solution to auto log into a website but I cant even get Selenium to stay open. It does what it is supposed to do right now and then quits immediately without a driver.quit().  I get the following errors and I wish to understand what they mean:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51111/devtools/browser/111111fe-423z-111zz-1116-r0z2300086f7
[3420:22152:1110/151643.950:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(387)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:  

[3420:22152:1110/151644.757:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(119)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a fallback task is shown, it is a bug. Please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
[3420:22152:1110/151647.899:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(119)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a fallback task is shown, it is a bug. Please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
Yahoo | Mail, Weather, Search, Politics, News, Finance, Sports & Videos
https://www.yahoo.com/
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

ser = Service("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Projects\\auto_login\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = ser)
driver.get("http://yahoo.com")
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: this could be a hung driver... check running tasks.  Be sure to use driver.quit() method each time you launch a driver.  The error is related to Edge authorization.. I think it requires a user to be logged in to the domain when running.... but seems like that is a red herring.  A previously orphaned webdriver is probably causing it.

Comment: Which version of Edge browser and Edge WebDriver are you using? Which version of Selenium are you using? I test with your code, it will show the errors you mention but the code can run well. Edge browser won't close unless I put `driver.quit()` at the end of the code. I think we can ignore the above errors.

Comment: Both are Version 95.0.1020.44, Selenium 4.

Comment: I think you're doing the right thing. Your selenium test is running well. I agree with DebanjanB's answer. You can ignore the error and check if you're using any python frameworks which make the browser close automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The errors you are seeing:

```
[3420:22152:1110/151643.950:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(387)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:  

[3420:22152:1110/151644.757:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(119)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a fallback task is shown, it is a bug. Please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
[3420:22152:1110/151647.899:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(119)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a fallback task is shown, it is a bug. Please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
```

are the result of a generic bug due to Chrome spawned a child process & Task Manager compatibility which you can ignore as of now. For details check [Issue 739782: [Task Manager] [Meta bug ☂️] Processes not shown in Task Manager](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739782).

Additionally, some specific python frameworks tends to close the browser automatically when all the lines of the program are executed successfully e.g. [Python-Unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503046/what-is-unittest-in-selenium-python/49516313#49516313) and have no relation with the errors explained above.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following code would disable the "DevTools listening on ..." errors (warnings?).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

I am using Selenium 4.5.0 and Edge driver Edge version 105.
It is basically the same code used for disabling these types of messages on Chrome drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium 4.6 with User-agent random

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import os
os.system("cls")



def User():
    
    ua = UserAgent()
    return ua.random


edgeOption = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.add_argument(f'user-agent={User()}')
edgeOption.add_argument("start-maximized")
s=service.Service(r'msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s, options=edgeOption)
driver.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='intro-body']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'][1]/div[@class='user-agent']/p[@class='intro-text']").text
ip = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='intro-body']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'][2]/div[@class='ip-address']/p[@class='intro-text']").text

print(user)
print(ip)
```