# Selenium tests are successfully executed but I get 0 passing, the assertions are being ignored

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to integrate Selenium (v4.18.1) tests into an Angular web application. The tests are to be conducted in the Microsoft Edge browser (v122.0.2365.59). I have already installed the Microsoft Edge WebDriver (v122.0.2365.59). Currently, I'm not working on custom tests; I'm starting with some assertions based on the example provided by Microsoft Learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=javascript&form=MA13LH

```
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const assert = require('assert');

(async () => {
    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();
    try {
        await driver.get('https://bing.com');

        const element = await driver.findElement(By.id('sb_form_q'));
        await element.sendKeys('WebDriver');
        await element.submit();

        // Example assertion: Verify that the page title contains the search query
        const pageTitle = await driver.getTitle();
        assert(pageTitle.includes('WebDriver'), 'Page title does not contain search query');

        // Example assertion: Verify that search results are displayed
        const searchResults = await driver.findElements(By.className('b_algo'));
        assert(searchResults.length > 0, 'No search results found');
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

After running npm test, the controlled Edge browser window opens, and the test runs successfully. However, afterward, I get the following issues:

$ npm test

> angular-17-crud@0.0.0 test
> npx mocha test/**/*.spec.js --timeout 60000

0 passing (1ms)

[31204:30320:0301/141401.539:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(157)] :components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(161) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. Please use the `--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management` command line flag to enable it if
you are not using the official Google Chrome build.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64707/devtools/browser/1aa5f86b-4683-4cee-b012-26c14eed17b2
[31204:30320:0301/141402.059:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(516)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:

[31204:30320:0301/141403.927:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(126)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.

I don't get why Google Chrome is being mentioned, and why are the tests running but the assertions are being ignored

I tried to verify the compatibility between the Edge browser, Selenium WebDriver, and the Microsoft Edge WebDriver. Although the errors aren't stopping the test execution, I suspect they might be the reason why I'm not receiving the results of the assertions

Comment: Where are you looking for the assertion results? I don't use JS but in general, asserts don't do anything unless they fail so you shouldn't see asserts passing. If you want to check, make the assert intentionally fail... do you see a fail message then? Depending on how you run the test, it's possible that you will break on the assert thrown.

Comment: You're right! The assertion didn't produce messages or results by itself when it was correct, and when I made it fail intentionally, I did get this message: 
**Error: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Page title does not contain search query
    at runTest(...)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator:'=='}**
Now I have implemented Mocha and I get results like 1 passing when it's correct and "0 passing 1 failing" when it's not.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I used your code for testing, and it shows the error you mentioned but the code works fine. I think we can ignore the error above since it's not pivotal. In addition, please note that "assertion" is only when false, a generic message indicating assertion failure is written to the console. You can refer to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/assert_static.

Comment: You're right as well, I implemented Mocha and now I get messages from the assertions when they pass and when they fail. Thank you very much!! Additionally, I managed to fix the weird errors with this other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914379/10394890

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's normal to answer your own question with the solution results, but here it is:

- I solved the weird errors with this other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914379/10394890
- Regarding the "assertions being ignored", it turned out to be due to the lack of a reporting handler.

I added the adaptation of the mentioned solution(EdgeOptions) along with Mocha, and got this fixed example:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Options: EdgeOptions } = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');

describe('Selenium tests', function() {
 let driver;

 before(async function() {
  // Set up EdgeOptions
  const options = new EdgeOptions();
  options.excludeSwitches('enable-logging');

  // Set up Selenium WebDriver
  driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge')
    .setEdgeOptions(options)
    .build();
 });

 after(async function() {
  // Clean up Selenium WebDriver after all tests are done
  await driver.quit();
 });

 it('should perform a search', async function() {
  await driver.get('https://bing.com');

  const element = await driver.findElement(By.id('sb_form_q'));
  await element.sendKeys('WebDriver');
  await element.submit();

  // Verify that the page title contains the search query
  const pageTitle = await driver.getTitle();
  assert(pageTitle.includes('WebDriver'), 'Page title does not contain search query');

  // Verify that search results are displayed
  const searchResults = await driver.findElements(By.className('b_algo'));
  assert(searchResults.length > 0, 'No search results found');
 });
});
```